# Looking for software library manager that runs scripts from searchable database

Tags: database, scripting

I am looking for a GUI program that stores scripts in a database which presents the scripts in a tree structure, like a Smalltalk image browser or the Microsoft Management Console, and it should enable searching for scripts and pop up a dialog for the input parameters and execute the script in a chosen directory.

Is there anything like that for Linux and Windows or close to it?